# Show specific hidden spans with jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a [contact form using Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) a bit further down where it says "with optional icons".
The contact form has 4 fields, 3 inputs for name, email and subject and 1 textarea for the message.
This is the contact form so far:

```
    <form action="contact_verify.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ingrese su Nombre *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 offset2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control span6" id="inputName" name="inputName" placeholder="Nombre">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group" id="email">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ingrese su Email *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 offset2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control span6" id="inputEmail" name="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputSubject" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ingrese su Asunto</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 offset2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control span6" id="inputSubject" name="inputSubject" placeholder="Asunto">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputText" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ingrese su consulta *</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 offset2">
                    <textarea class="form-control span6" rows="5" id="inputText" name="inputText" placeholder="Escriba su consulta..."></textarea>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="form-group offset7">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Now I can hide the spans with jquery using:

```
$("span").hide();
```

My goal is once the person starts writing on each field the hidden span with bootstrap appears on that field. 
So far I have managed that each field is green once the person stops typing with this function:

```
$(".form-group").keyup(function(){
    $(this).addClass("has-success has-feedback");
});
```

But at the moment I can't figure out how to make the focused input or textarea show the hidden span of it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 $(this).next().show();
```

or

```
 $(this).siblings('span').show();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/renos/1/edit)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I already tried $(this).next().show(); and it didn't worked, tried the other one and it's not working either

Comment: The demo is working, though the span appears outside the input, instead of inside like the bootstrap demo. I'll check it and see if I can make it work. Thank you all though

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confliction, you should try like this:

```
$("span.form-control-feedback").hide();
$(".form-control").keyup(function(){
    $(this).siblings('span.form-control-feedback').show();
});
```

if the SPAN is styled properly (may be absolute), then it will be on the INPUT fields.